# Error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'namespace'

Tags: c++, syntax, sstream

I am VERY new to C++ and Open GL and I have been trying to display 3D objects in a scene. it worked fine with one but when I tried to alter my code to add a second, my code regarding the HUD text showing the camera location started giving errors. The error above is shown and it is apparently in the sstream file (#include). I have tried searching around and asking for help but there is nothing that helps/that I understand. When I comment-out the #include line and the code that uses it, I get a similar saying "error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'using'" in my main.cpp file.

I am running Visual Studio 2010 and I have even tried turning the whole thing off and on again, and copying the code over to a new project. Help would be greatly appreciated.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <GL/gl.h>
#include <GL/glu.h>
#include "glut.h"
#include "SceneObject.h"
#include <fstream>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
//#include <cmath>
//#include <limits>
//#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;
```

...

```
stringstream ss;
ss << "Camera (" << cam.pos.x << ", " << cam.pos.y << ", " << cam.pos.z << ")";
glClear(GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
outputText(-1.0, 0.5, ss.str());
```

...

```
#ifndef SCENEOBJECT_H
#define SCENEOBJECT_H
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

using namespace std;

struct point3D {
    float x;
    float y;
    float z;
};

struct colour{
    float r;
    float g;
    float b;
};

struct tri {
    int a;
    int b;
    int c;
};

class SceneObject {
private:
    int NUM_VERTS;
    int NUM_COL;
    int NUM_TRI;
    point3D  * vertices;
    colour * colours;
    tri  * indices;
    void drawTriangle(int a, int b, int c);
public:
    SceneObject(const string fName) {
        read_file(fName);
    }
    void drawShape()
    {
        // DO SOMETHING HERE
    }
    int read_file (const string fileName)
    {
    ifstream inFile;
    inFile.open(fileName);

    if (!inFile.good())
    {
        cerr  << "Can't open file" << endl;
        NUM_TRI = 0;
        return 1;
    }

    //inFile >> shapeID;

    inFile >> NUM_VERTS;
    vertices = new point3D[NUM_VERTS];

    for (int i=0; i < NUM_VERTS; i++)
    {   
        inFile >> vertices[i].x;
        inFile >> vertices[i].y;
        inFile >> vertices[i].z;
    }

    inFile >> NUM_COL;
    //inFile >> randomCol;
    colours = new colour[NUM_COL];
    /*if (randomCol == 'y')
    {
        for (int i=0; i < NUM_COL; i++)
        {
            colours[i].r = ((float) rand() / (RAND_MAX+1));
            colours[i].g = ((float) rand() / (RAND_MAX+1));
            colours[i].b = ((float) rand() / (RAND_MAX+1));
        }
    }
    else if (randomCol == 'n')
    {*/
        for (int i=0; i < NUM_COL; i++)
        {   
            inFile >> colours[i].r;
            inFile >> colours[i].g;
            inFile >> colours[i].b;
        }
    //}

    inFile >> NUM_TRI;
    indices = new tri[NUM_TRI];

    for (int i=0; i < NUM_TRI; i++)
    {   
        inFile >> indices[i].a;
        inFile >> indices[i].b;
        inFile >> indices[i].c;
    }

    inFile.close();
    return 0;
}
}
#endif
```

I haven't changed the  code and as far as I am aware, there are semi-colons where there are meant to be. Even my friend who has been programming for 5 years couldn't solve this. I will include any other specific code if needed. And when I said new to C++ and OpenGL I really much VERY new.
This is even my first post. I'll get there eventually.

Comment: Instead of attempting to describe your code, remove all doubt by simply showing it to us. Please edit your question and show code. Usually this error comes when you forget a `;` at the end of a `struct` or `class`.

Comment: Well, you're missing a `;` somewhere, probably at the end of a class declaration

Comment: Or more specifically, *before a namespace declaration*.

Comment: Since the only non-system include is "SceneObject.h", you should start looking in there.

Comment: Looks like we have a typographical close reason for this these days.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

you have to put a ';' after each class

That means

```
class foo{
public:
   void bar();
};
```

and i think you miss the last semicolon.

Comment: Excuse me while I go hang myself...
This is the sort of stuff they don't point out to you in classes -_-

Comment: There is no reason to hang up yourself ^^ I think most of the people here do the same mistakes ^^

Comment: Also, if you forget the ';' in a method declaration in a .h file, it can mess up the next thing in the .cpp file after that include.

Answer (score 1):

Your class `SceneObject` does not have a `;` at the end. This is probably the missing `;` the error message is referring to. It is most likely causing your problems once you include the header in your code.

This is exactly what Mat and David suggested before.

Answer (score 0):

Every including/function/call etc. has a body wich executes a line of code, because C++ ignores whitespace you will need to tell the program when the line stops this would run only an action and not confuse it with others, to tell your program when an action ends you put a `";"`

Because you need to compile C++ apps you will run into an error when you don't do this right.
wich is the error you are running into so find out where you miss the `";"` and add it

I hope this helps you out.

Comment: I have just included the code above and it is claiming the error in something that I haven't even written, and before anything that I have have written

Answer (score 0):

You should look at all files you included in this one. Perhaps in  "SceneObject.h"..
seems to be a lack of ";" but also verifies the "{" "}" and "(" ")" because mistakes can sometimes be a bit tricky.